# How can I change Jupyter output font in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

I'm trying to use PyCharm's Jupyter integration to write Python tutorials that I'll use on live workshops. However, I can't change the iPython output font. Any tips on how to do this?

I want to change these font sizes:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still unsolved. Upvote here to increase priority: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53404/Rendered-Markdown-font-size-customization-in-Jupyter-Notebook-cells

Answer (score 5):

[image]

you can go to `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Jupyter`

and uncheck the `Use Editor Font Size` option, set the font size you want.

Setting the font type is not currently supported.

Comment: This setting is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Appearance > "Override default fonts by (not recommended)"

I had the same issue. By selecting 'Monospaced' for as font, the Jupyter output aligns properly, when you work with character widths

Comment: Tried it. Didn't change the fonts indicated in the question. It did, however, change the font of the PyCharm menus, buttons, dialogs, etc.... which is "not recommended" for a reason: it breaks the layout of pretty much everything.

Comment: That is correct. searching through the setting  I can't find a specific setting besides changing the entire font. Yes it is overkill, but it works to align width depend output.

Comment: Note you have to rerun the functions in the notebook for the output font to be different after doing this.

Answer (score -4):

File --> Settings --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts --> Font

Answer (score -5):

Editor -> Colors & fonts -> Console font

Comment: That only changes the font on the console. I want to change the font on the notebook editor

Comment: It doesn't control your font in notebook